# Why does $1-\frac{1+n}{4+2n}=\frac{3+n}{4+2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an understanding of proofs and I came to the point where $1-\frac{1+n}{4+2n}=\frac{3+n}{4+2n}$. I couldn't figure out why the math worked out though. Could someone explain to my why this math works out?

Comment: Just add the two terms on the left of the equal sign!

Comment: Hint:  $1={4+2n\over 4+2n}$.

Comment: @WillO Thank you. I can't believe I didn't remember that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes the argument (assuming $4+2n\neq 0$):

$$\begin{align}1-\frac{1+n}{4+2n}&=\frac{4+2n}{4+2n}-\frac{1+n}{4+2n}\\ \\ &=\frac{(4+2n)-(1+n)}{4+2n}\\ \\ &=\frac{4-1+2n-n}{4+2n}=\frac{3+n}{4+2n}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Reducing to the same denominator one has

$$1-\frac{1+n}{4+2n}=\frac{4+2n-1-n}{4+2n}$$